# Is there a way to set a breakpoint for Xcode Console warnings?

Tags: xcode, xcode9

I am getting a warning that I know is directly triggered somewhere in my code. Is there a way that I can set a breakpoint for a specific or even all warnings that the console prints out?

Comment: Breakpoints are triggered at runtime. Warnings are usually emitted by the compiler during compilation. Breakpoints occur in the debugger while the code is executing. What would you expect to catch them when it's being compiled?

Comment: It depends upon the particular warning you're trying to capture. There's not a generalized mechanism to catch runtime warnings, but a few (notably auto layout warnings) allow you to add explicit breakpoints for them. If you tell us which warning you're hoping to catch, we might be able to help you, but there is no generalized "stop if there is a warning" mechanism.

Comment: This is the warning: attempt to present * on * which is already presenting

Comment: No, I don't believe you can set either an exception breakpoint, a Swift error breakpoint, or a symbolic breakpoint for that.